# Callback byte[] from native c++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, native-code

I have a c++ native dll (NOT CLR) , that have callback to c# application.
All callbacks works except the following:

C++:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *TransmitBinaryMessageCallback)(GUID connectionID, byte data[], int data_size);
```

call :

```
GUID ClientID = { 0x12345678, 0xabcd, 0xef12, { 0xfe, 0xdc, 0xa9, 0x87, 0x65, 0x43, 0x21, 0x11 } };
byte arrayB[10] = {0x2,0x4,0x6,0x8,0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0xff};
transmitBINMessage(ClientID,arrayB,10);
```

C#

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate int TransmitBinaryMessageCallback(Guid ClientID,byte [] data,int data_size

public static int FuncTransmitBinaryMessageCallback(Guid ClientID, byte[] data, int data_size)
{
    try
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("transmitBinaryMessageCallback: clientID=" + ClientID.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
            "data=" + data.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
            "data_size=" + data_size.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I get only the first byte => 0x2

I tried also:

```
char[] arrayBytes = new char[data_size];
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));
int i = reader.Read(arrayBytes, 0, data_size);
```

i = 0 :(

What i'm missing?

> I could change in c++ from byte [] to char* and in C# to string ->
>   this work. BUT i want byte array, why it not work?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marshaller doesn't know how long the byte array is. It has no way to marshal it. I would declare `data` to be `IntPtr` and then use `Marshal.Copy` to copy from the unmanaged memory to a byte array.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate int TransmitBinaryMessageCallback(Guid ClientID, IntPtr dataPtr, int data_size);
```

And then inside the callback implementation

```
byte[] data = new byte[data_size];
Marshal.Copy(dataPtr, data, 0, data_size);
```

Comment: This is probably a better way to go than my thought.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't entirely up on what extensions Microsoft has put on top of C++ but I don't believe there is currently a `byte` type in C++. I created  new MFC DLL project to have a look. Their `byte` type is nothing more than `typedef unsigned char byte;`

Try changing your signature to

`typedef int (__stdcall *TransmitBinaryMessageCallback)(GUID connectionID, byte* data, int data_size);`

Comment: You are right, I saw that (typedef unsigned char byte), but what you are asking is the same, in c++: xx[] is the same as *xx , NO?

Comment: Mostly. If you define x[], the contents are mutable via `x[i] =`. If you define `x* =`, whatever is on the rhs is copied into memory and `x` is a pointer to that memory. I think David's answer above explains why it doesn't work. The marshaller can't figure out who long the array is because there's built in `length` like in C#. The disadvantage to his approach is the performance hit of the additional copy (if say you were marshalling the binary data of a camera's input per frame for example).

Comment: @Ternary in C++ `sometype x[]` and `sometype* x` as parameter declarations are completely interchangeable. If you want to avoid the copy you can do so. The most efficient would be unsafe code and declare the parameter as a pointer. If onward processing requires a managed array then the copy is unavoidable. FWIW the first sentence of this comment means that this answer is simply wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yea agreed given the semantics of this question the two are totally interchangeable. The OP's question was "in c++: xx[] is the same as *xx" which strictly speaking they aren't. Once is an array, the other is a pointer to an array.

Comment: @Ternary implicit is the context of being parameter declarations

Comment: @Ternary you are right, one is array (as you cant define byte xx[] without define the size,mean: byte xx[10]), and one is pointer to array. I meant in both cases you can use the xx as a pointer to the data (in byte *xx: after allocated the data), both same when access data: *(xx+y) <=> xx[y]